# Why do I get an error trying to render a component in a variable?

Tags: reactjs

I have a situation where I want to render a default component, UNLESS a different one is passed in an object.

```
  {map(changes, item => {
    const hasChanged = item.fromValue !== item.toValue;
    const Component = item.Component;

    return (
      <div key={uuid.v4()} className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          {Component ? (
            <Component
              key={uuid.v4()}
              labelColor={hasChanged ? '#AB2912' : ''}
              backgroundColor={hasChanged ? '#FFEE7E' : ''}
              shouldBoldValue={hasChanged}
              label={item.label}
              cssClasses="preview-item-padding"
              capitalize={false} />
          ) : (
              <SimpleLabelText
                key={uuid.v4()}
                labelColor={hasChanged ? '#AB2912' : ''}
                backgroundColor={hasChanged ? '#FFEE7E' : ''}
                shouldBoldValue={hasChanged}
                label={item.label}
                text={item.toValue}
                cssClasses="preview-item-padding"
                capitalize={false} />
            )}

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
```

In that code above, I want to render `SimpleLabelText` unless the `item` object has a Component property. `Component` is a jsx tag created in a different file.

I don't think it matters, but here is the function that creates the tag in the other file (this is temporary, I'm going to add stuff to it later)

```
function getCustomComponent(text) {
  return (
    <SimpleLabelText
      text='something'
    />
  );
}
```

However, when I run this, the whole thing explodes and I get this error message;

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: . Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?

How can I properly render the jxg tag that is getting assigned to `Component`?

Answer (score 3):

I hope your `item.component` is the result of calling `getCustomComponent()`. Here you need to notice that `getCustomComponent` returns an object and not an `function` or `class`. So you have to directly render it like `{item.Component}` instead of using this -> `< />` notation.

Keeping this in mind, your code would transform to something like below.

```
 return (
  <div key={uuid.v4()} className="row">
    <div className="col-md-6">
      { item.Component ? item.Component : (
          <SimpleLabelText
            key={uuid.v4()}
            labelColor={hasChanged ? '#AB2912' : ''}
            backgroundColor={hasChanged ? '#FFEE7E' : ''}
            shouldBoldValue={hasChanged}
            label={item.label}
            text={item.toValue}
            cssClasses="preview-item-padding"
            capitalize={false} />
        )}

    </div>
  </div>
);
```

But this does not entirely solve your problem. The props that you need to pass is not getting passed now(in case of `item.Component` being present). So you might need to look at `React.cloneElement`. You can read about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement and some examples online of how to get your props passed to your `item.Component` and render the same.

Comment: I didn't know that I couldn't just use ` <Component />`. Is there any way to pass the component and still render it using the <> tags?

Comment: That is why i have mentioned about `React.cloneElement`. Once you extend the object with props you can render it using `<>` tags. You can read examples on the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{ () => (Component ? <Component /> : <SimpleLabelText />) }
```

abbreviated for brevity. The inside of the brackets needs to be a function that returns your component. The other main issue that causes this error message would be from your import statements, so please include that as well.